# Laravel 5.4 : Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have trouble saving image or fileupload in laravel 5.4.
    the admin is the only one allowed to register a user together with his/her image upon registering the user should receive a confirmation email on his inbox. for other related codes that I think that is related to this controller and the email function or method that could have messed up my code.
paste bin https://pastebin.com/h3Sj7sGN?

```
   //UserController
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Str;
   use Mail;
   use App\Mail\verifyEmail;


   class UserController extends Controller
   {
   /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
   public function index()
   {
    $users = User::all();

    //Load all users on the table and pass the users
    $users = User::where(['archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('usercrud.index')->with('users', $users);      
    }




    public function create(Request $request)
    {
    //
    if ($request->file('images') == null)
    {
       $file = "";
    }else{

    $filename = $request->images->getClientOriginalName();

    $filesize = $request->images->getClientSize();

    $file = $request->file('images')->storeAs('images', $filename);

    $usersSt = new User;
    $usersSt->filename = $filename;
    $usersSt->filesize = $filesize;
    $usersSt->position = $request->companyPos;
    $usersSt->empid = $request->empid;
    $usersSt->name = $request->fullname;
    $usersSt->email = $request->email;
    $usersSt->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $usersSt->roles = $request->role_id;
    $usersSt->save();
     }

     $users = User::all();
     $users = User::where(['archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get();
     $thisUser = User::findOrFail($users->id);
    $this->sendEmail($thisUser);

    $thisUser = User::findOrFail($users->id);
    dd($id);
    $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
    return redirect()->to('userIndex')->with('users', $users);
    return $request->all();


    }    

    public function verifyEmailFirst(Request $request)
    {
    //
    return view('usercrud.verifyEmailFirst');
    }

    /*  public function emailtoken(Request $request)
    {
        //
        return 

    }  */      

    /**


   public function edit($id)
   {
    //
    $users = User::where(['id'=>$id])->first();


    // dd($users);

     return view('usercrud.edit',compact('users'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
     //
    $usersUp = new User;
    $password = bcrypt($request->editpassword);


    // dd($request->editcompanyPos);

    $usersUp = User::where('id',$id)
        ->update(['position'=>$request->editcompanyPos,'name'=>$request- 
         >editfullname,'email'=>$request- 
         >editemail,'password'=>$password,'roles'=>$request->editrole_id]);

      $users = User::all();
     $users = User::where(['archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get();

     return redirect()->to('userIndex')->with('users', $users);
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
    $userDel = User::where('id',$id)->update(['archive'=>0]);

    $users = User::all();
    $users = User::where(['archive'=>1])->orderBy('id')->get();

    return redirect()->to('userIndex')->with('users', $users);

    }

    public function sendEmail($thisUser)
     {
    Mail::to($thisUser['email'])->send(new verifyEmail($thisUser));
     }

     public function sendEmailDone($email, $verifyToken)
    {
    $user = User::where(['email'=>$email, 'verifyToken'=>$verifyToken])- 
     >first();
    //return $user;
    if ($user){
        return user::where(['email'=>$email, 'verifyToken'=>$verifyToken])- 
        >update(['status'=>'1','verifyToken'=>NULL]);

    }else{
        return 'user not found';
    }

    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
//
if ($request->file('images') == null)
{
   $file = "";
}else{

$filename = $request->images->getClientOriginalName();

$filesize = $request->images->getClientSize();

$file = $request->file('images')->storeAs('images', $filename);

$usersSt = new User;
$usersSt->filename = $filename;
$usersSt->filesize = $filesize;
$usersSt->position = $request->companyPos;
$usersSt->empid = $request->empid;
$usersSt->name = $request->fullname;
$usersSt->email = $request->email;
$usersSt->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$usersSt->roles = $request->role_id;
$usersSt->save();
 }


$this->sendEmail($usersSt);

return redirect()->to('userIndex')->with('users', $usersSt);
}
```